# Changing transition of Master Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using MasterSlider which is great but I cant find a way to make nice transitions between slides (not layers). I see there is a parameter known as "view" which accepts some transitions like "fade", "mask"... But I would like to be able to allow more transitions, like skew, rotate... when the slide appears/disappears. Is there any option to make the slide appear/disappear with a nice transition?

Comment: Maybe this will be of some use for you? http://www.masterslider.com/transition-gallery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a documentation on masterslider and its transitions: 
http://www.masterslider.com/doc/#views

Also you can view the transitions here:
http://www.masterslider.com/transition-gallery/

Searching for 'master slider transitions' on google got me there.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, this is hardly a programming issue. This is question is due to lack of research. Also if you choose to post an answer with links to documentation it is recommended that you include some examples of that source code as some links expire and become useless for future use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that the transition gallery does not apply to slides, but to layers.